# Sort objects based on other objects' properties in controller function using ES6 classes

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I want to sort some projects based on their country using a custom function: `customSort`.
The projects only reference the country by id, so I need to retrieve the name from a `country` objects array.
In HTML my sorting looks like this:
`ng-repeat="customer in $ctrl.customers | orderBy:'country':false:$ctrl.customSort"`

`orderBy:'country'` is irrelevant, as that is just the id, but I don't know how to skip this parameter.

Since I switched to ES6 classes `customSort` is not working because `this` isn't there yet.

**How can I make the sorting work with this ES6 class?**

Here's the minified problem:

```js
class Ctrl {
  constructor() {
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.customers = [{
      id: 1,
      country: 1,
    }, {
      id: 2,
      country: 2,
    }, {
      id: 3,
      country: 3,
    }];
    
   this.countries = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "USA",
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: "Germany",
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: "France",
    }];
  }

  customSort(customer1,customer2) {
    let name1 = this.countries[customer1.country];
    let name2 = this.countries[customer2.country];
    return name1.localeCompare(name2);
  }

}

angular.module('app', []).controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl as $ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="customer in $ctrl.customers | orderBy:'name':false:$ctrl.customSort">
      <input type="text" ng-model="customer.name">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `$ctrl.customSort` is a **comparator** for *orderBy* filter. It already passes the reference to the customer object. Accept it as a parameter: `customSort(cust) { ... }`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I added it as a parameter, but the problem is that I need information from the other object `sortObject` for sorting as well